# Spark Decimal Precision and Scale seems wrong when Casting

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Reading the documentation, a Spark DataType BigDecimal(precision, scale) means that

- **Precision** is total number of digits and
- **Scale** is the number of digits after the decimal point.

So when I cast a value to decimal

```
scala> val sss = """select cast(1.7142857343 as decimal(9,8))"""
scala> spark.sql(sss).show
+----------------------------------+
|CAST(1.7142857343 AS DECIMAL(9,8))|
+----------------------------------+
|                        1.71428573|  // It has 8 decimal digits
+----------------------------------+
```

But when I cast values above 10.0, I get NULL

```
scala> val sss = """select cast(12.345678901 as decimal(9,8))"""
scala> spark.sql(sss).show
+----------------------------+
|CAST(11.714 AS DECIMAL(9,8))|
+----------------------------+
|                        null|
+----------------------------+
```

I would expect the result would be **12.3456789**,

- Why is it NULL?
- Why is it that Precision is not being implemented?

Comment: Your table header is showing different number being cast as bigdecimal. Are you sure you executed the right statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cast decimal spark internally validates that provided schema decimal(9,8) is wider than 12.345678901 actual schema decimal(11,9). If yes, it means numbers can be casted into provided schema safely without losing any precision or range. Have a look at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.isWiderThan()

However, in the above case decimal(11,9) can not be cast into decimal(9,8) therefore it is returning null.

```
//MAX_PRECISION = 38
val sss = """select cast(12.345678901 as decimal(38,7))"""
spark.sql(sss1).show(10)
+-----------------------------------+
|CAST(12.345678901 AS DECIMAL(38,8))|
+-----------------------------------+
|                         12.3456789|
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it truncate if it is not wider than?